# Using "using" directive to shorten function definition

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have stumbled upon an unusual to me usage of `using namespace` directive:

Given a header file `WeirdNamespace.h`:

```
namespace WeirdNamespace
{

class WeirdClass
{
public:
    int x;

    void go();
};

}
```

I have a matching 'WeirdNamespace.cpp`:

```
#include "WeirdNamespace.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace WeirdNamespace;

void WeirdClass::go()
{
    std::cout << "Reached go?!" << std::endl;
}
```

The class is used as follows:

```
#include "WeirdNamespace.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{   
    WeirdNamespace::WeirdClass c;
    c.go();
}
```

Until now I have never seen the using directive used to avoid reopening the namespace in the cpp file or prefixing method names with the namespace name. Is it a correct usage of the directive? Are there any pitfalls specific to this scenario, except for the usual `using namespace` caveats?

Comment: `using namespace NamespaceName` makes available all the names in `NamespaceName`. Instead you can do `using NamespaceName::ClassName`

Comment: Or you can just "reopen" the namespace...

Comment: My guess is that the author just did it for the sake of convenience. It certainly appears to be a valid usage of the `using` directive - I've never heard any rule that you can only use it to shorten method/class invocations rather than definitions. I'm not a C++ expert, however.

Comment: For some reason this is actually *the* way that Clang (and I guess LLVM) are coded. Personally I just reopen the namespace...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do:

```
namespace WN = WeirdNamespace;
WN::WeirdClass c;
```

**Now, I got the question! The above is no answer**.

Quoting from [7.3.4] Using directive

> "During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names appear as if they
>   were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both
>   the using-directive and the nominated namespace."

Hence your definition in the source without enclosing it in the namespace is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is valid but there is a pitfall:

`using namespace NamespaceName` will make available all the names in `NamespaceName`.

So instead you can use `using` to use only the class name:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "WeirdNamespace.h"

using WeiredNamespace::WeiredClass;

void WeiredClass::go() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. The asker found this pattern in somebody else's code and is curious about whether it is valid, and whether there are any drawbacks. The question is not about basic behavior of namespaces (or really namespaces at all), but really the `using` directive.

Comment: Ok... there was some misunderstanding about the question.... but now I have edited it. But I still have kept the example of the namespace as the better alternative for the job...