# Why does the using directive not "associate" with ordinary functions?

Tags: c++, namespaces

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556714) it is valid to define class methods after a `using` directive, instead of enclosing them within a `namespace` block.

However, that seems not to be the case for ordinary functions. Consider:

#### `Greeting.hh`

```
#pragma once

namespace NS
{
    class Greeting
    {
    public:
        void hello();
    };

    void otherHello();
}
```

#### `Greeting.cc`

```
#include "Greeting.hh"
#include <iostream>

using namespace NS;

void Greeting::hello()
{
    std::cout << "Greeting::hello" << std::endl;
}

void otherHello()
{
    std::cout << "otherHello" << std::endl;
}
```

#### `main.cc`

```
#include "Greeting.hh"

int main()
{
    NS::Greeting o;
    o.hello();
    NS::otherHello();
}
```

This won't compile, yielding the following error message:

```
undefined reference to `NS::otherHello()'
```

Further inspection indicates that `otherHello`'s symbol is not preceded by the namespace, while `Greeting::hello`'s is:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -c Greeting.cc
nm -C Greeting.o | grep T
000000000000002a T otherHello()
0000000000000000 T NS::Greeting::hello()
```

Does this contradict with the Standard reference from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18556784/586873)?

> "During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names appear as if they
>   were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both
>   the using-directive and the nominated namespace."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's important to remember is that

1. Function declarations in different namespaces don't interfere with each other.
2. A definition of a function is also a declaration.
3. [[namespace.def/4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.def#4)

> **The enclosing namespaces of a declaration are those namespaces in
>   which the declaration lexically appears**, except for a redeclaration of
>   a namespace member outside its original namespace (e.g., a definition
>   as specified in [namespace.memdef]). Such a redeclaration has the same
>   enclosing namespaces as the original declaration.

So let's look at the `otherHello` definition. Where does it lexically appear? In the global namespace of course. That's also the point of declaration for it. Which means the enclosing namespace is the global one, and you end up with a declaration of `::otherHello`.

So no, this doesn't contradict the standard quote from the accepted answer to the other question. Member functions can be defined outside of the class, so long as they are qualified by their class name ([[class.mfct/4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#class.mfct-4)):

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class
>   definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class
>   name using the ​::​ operator.

So we need only ask, does `Greeting` name the same class as `NS::Greeting`? Why, yes it does. The using directive is responsible for that.

---

I'll add this segment in the hope of clarifying. Consider this code snippet:

```
namespace NS1 {
    namespace NS2 {
        void hello();
    }
}

using namespace NS1;

void NS2::hello() {

}

int main() {
    NS1::NS2::hello();
    return 0;
}
```

When the compiler encounters `NS2::hello` being defined it preforms name lookup for that declarator id. According to [[basic.lookup.qual/3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#3):

> In a declaration in which the declarator-id is a qualified-id, **names
>   used before the qualified-id being declared are looked up in the
>   defining namespace scope**; names following the qualified-id are looked
>   up in the scope of the member's class or namespace.

So `NS2` is looked up in the defining scope (the global one), and according to the unqualified name lookup rule you quoted, it is found and resolved as `NS1::NS2`. That's how `NS2::hello` is associated with `NS1::NS2::hello` and resolved as defining it.

In the global namespace of the OP, `otherHello` isn't preceded by anything. Therefore name lookup doesn't occur. It immediately defines that function in the enclosing namespace, as I previously quoted.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski - Like I specified, the definition includes also a declaration into the enclosing namespace (the global one). There is no association that *can* happen. The two are semantically different. Unlike `Greeting`, which *can* name `NS::Greeting`. And so can be used when defining `NS::Greeting::hello`.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski - There's no name lookup going on at all because you skip to defining the name `::otherHello` immediately. On the other hand, you do preform name lookup for `Greeting`. The same can be observed with nested namespaces. [See here](http://ideone.com/leW1rA). The using directive pulls in the namesapce NS2. That's why I can define `NS2::hello`. The point is that in one case, there is a name component that can be resolved by the using directive. And in the other, it can't. It's just a definition in the global namespace.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski - *The same happens* what is "the same"? If it introduces a new class, that's to be expected **by the very same reasoning I presented**. And I would not take too much stalk in cppreference. It's excellent, but not the standard. I've explained as fully as possible, and have nothing to add.